# Objects in array removed, but not dealloc'd

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, automatic-ref-counting

I'm working on a scrollview which contains a list of views built from a custom class. This class is a view that has an image and a delete button and a delegate. When I press the delete button, it calls the delegate function (the delegate is the scrollview and the scrollview removes the view from the array to delete it). The problem I have is that when the delete button is pressed, the item is removed on the array but isn't dealloc'd so the button and image remain on screen.

I'm using ARC for the first time and I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong. Usually I'd be okay with using retain and release and I'd be able to debug this but ARC feels mysterious to me and I'm a bit stumped why the view isn't getting dealloc'd.

Here's my code:

VideoScrollView:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "VideoButtonView.h"

@interface VideoScrollView: UIScrollView <VideoButtonViewDelegate>

@property (retain, nonatomic)          NSMutableArray *buttonArray;

- (void)setScrollViewContentSize: (CGSize) minimumSize;
- (void)buttonAdded: (UIImage*)image withMinimumSize: (CGSize) minimumSize;
- (void)respondToDelete:(id)sender;

@end


#import "VideoScrollView.h"

@implementation VideoScrollView


#define BUTTON_SIDE_LENGTH 60
#define BUTTON_BUFFER_LENGTH 10
#define INSET_HEIGHT 0
#define INSET_WIDTH 0

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.buttonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.buttonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:decoder];
    if (self) {
        self.buttonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}


-(BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view {
    if([view class] == [UIButton class])
        return true;
    return [super touchesShouldCancelInContentView:view];
}

- (void)setScrollViewContentSize: (CGSize) minimumSize {
    float scrollViewWidth = self.frame.size.width;
    float buttons_per_row = scrollViewWidth / (BUTTON_SIDE_LENGTH + BUTTON_BUFFER_LENGTH);
    float num_rows = ceil([self.buttonArray count] / floorf( buttons_per_row ));

    self.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(INSET_HEIGHT, INSET_WIDTH, INSET_HEIGHT, INSET_WIDTH);

    CGFloat min_width = minimumSize.height - INSET_HEIGHT*2;
    CGFloat acutal_width = (BUTTON_SIDE_LENGTH + BUTTON_BUFFER_LENGTH) * num_rows + BUTTON_BUFFER_LENGTH;
    CGFloat contentHeight = MAX(acutal_width, min_width);
    CGSize temp_size = CGSizeMake(minimumSize.width, contentHeight);
    self.contentSize = temp_size;
}

- (void)setButtonLocations {
    float scrollViewWidth = self.frame.size.width;
    float buttons_per_row = scrollViewWidth / (BUTTON_SIDE_LENGTH + BUTTON_BUFFER_LENGTH);
    //float num_rows = 0;
    //num_rows = ceil([self.buttonArray count] / floorf( buttons_per_row ));

    float offset = scrollViewWidth - (BUTTON_SIDE_LENGTH + BUTTON_BUFFER_LENGTH)*buttons_per_row + BUTTON_BUFFER_LENGTH;
    offset/=2;

    int count = 0;
    for(UIButton *button in self.buttonArray) {
        CGFloat button_x = (CGFloat)(count % (int)buttons_per_row)*(BUTTON_SIDE_LENGTH + BUTTON_BUFFER_LENGTH) + BUTTON_BUFFER_LENGTH + offset;
        CGFloat button_y = (CGFloat)floorf(count / (int)buttons_per_row)*(BUTTON_SIDE_LENGTH + BUTTON_BUFFER_LENGTH) + BUTTON_BUFFER_LENGTH;

        button.frame = CGRectMake(button_x, button_y, BUTTON_SIDE_LENGTH, BUTTON_SIDE_LENGTH);

        count++;
    }
}

- (void)buttonAdded: (UIImage*)image withMinimumSize: (CGSize) minimumSize {
    int scrollViewWidth = self.frame.size.width;
    int buttons_per_row = scrollViewWidth / (BUTTON_SIDE_LENGTH + BUTTON_BUFFER_LENGTH);

    int button_count = [self.buttonArray count];
    CGFloat button_x = (CGFloat)(button_count % buttons_per_row)*(BUTTON_SIDE_LENGTH + BUTTON_BUFFER_LENGTH) + BUTTON_BUFFER_LENGTH;
    CGFloat button_y = (CGFloat)floor(button_count / buttons_per_row)*(BUTTON_SIDE_LENGTH + BUTTON_BUFFER_LENGTH) + BUTTON_BUFFER_LENGTH;

    VideoButtonView* temp_button_view = [[VideoButtonView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(button_x, button_y, BUTTON_SIDE_LENGTH, BUTTON_SIDE_LENGTH)];
    temp_button_view.delegate = self;

    [self addSubview:temp_button_view];

    [self.buttonArray addObject:temp_button_view];

    [self setScrollViewContentSize:minimumSize];
}

- (void)respondToDelete: (id)sender
{
    [self.buttonArray removeObject:sender];

}

@end
```

VideoButtonView:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol VideoButtonViewDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)respondToDelete: (id)sender;

@end

@interface VideoButtonView : UIView


@property (retain, nonatomic) UIButton *videoButton;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIButton *deleteButton;

@property(nonatomic,assign)id<VideoButtonViewDelegate> delegate;

@end

#import "VideoButtonView.h"

#define DELETE_BUTTON_LENGTH 5

@implementation VideoButtonView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.videoButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        [self.videoButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

        self.deleteButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];

        [self setFrame:frame];

        [self.deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deletePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self.deleteButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"delete_button.png"]
                                              stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:8.0f
                                              topCapHeight:0.0f]
                                            forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self.deleteButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.deleteButton setTitle:@"Delete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.deleteButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:6];
        self.deleteButton.titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        self.deleteButton.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1);

        [self addSubview:self.videoButton];
        [self addSubview:self.deleteButton];

        [self bringSubviewToFront:self.deleteButton];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)deletePressed: (id)sender {
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(respondToDelete:)])
    {
        //send the delegate function with the amount entered by the user
        [self.delegate respondToDelete:self];
    }

}

-(void) setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    [super setFrame:frame];

    CGRect video_frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
    [self.videoButton setFrame:video_frame];
    [self.videoButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    CGFloat delete_y = frame.size.height - 15;
    CGRect deleteFrame = CGRectMake(10, delete_y, 40, 10);
    [self.deleteButton setFrame:deleteFrame];
}



/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array of buttons is just keeping references to the buttons that are on the view. By removing an item from the array you aren't removing it from the view, just from the array. You need to have something like this instead:

```
- (void)respondToDelete: (id)sender {
    [sender removeFromSuperview];
    [self.buttonArray removeObject:sender];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call

```
[self addSubview:yourSubview]
```

your subview is added to self and a strong pointer is added to self.subviews. The first thing you need to do when you want to remove the subView is calling

```
[yourSubview removeFromSuperView]
```

Then if you remove also any other strong pointer to the subview that you have the dealloc method will be called.